# Wrong quote style with pdo_informix

Tags: php, pdo, informix

I am using PDO_Informix (1.3.0) with a Informix (11) database.
However when I use the pdo::quote command the escape of a single quote is wrong (yes I know I should use prepare statements). Pdo::quote escapes a single quote with a backslash like this 'it\'s' while it should escape the single quote with an extra single quote like  this 'it''s'.
Can I tell the driver to use the proper quoting style?